# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle: accessing DB inside profile build form

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm using FOSUserBundle on Symfony2.

I've extended the profile form type to include my fields.

I'd like to pre-populate one of those fields with one value found in DB (not in the user entity).

Basically I need to access DB from inside the buildForm.

I don't want (if possible) to override the original controller.

EDIT: I probably cannot use the "entity" field type as that (as far as I understand) creates the equivalent of a choice (with values loaded from DB). I need to have the field editable. I need to have access to the current user entity so that I have access to its ID. With that ID I can perform a query and get a text value from my DB (it's a license associated to the user) and use that value to populate one of the text fields of my form. Could I possibly override the getLicense() method of the user class to perform my queries there? How can I have access to DB inside an entity?

Hints?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need the Entity field:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Here's an example:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{        
    $builder->add('foobar', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'DummyBundle:Test',
                'property' => 'name',
                'multiple' => false,
                'expanded' => false,
                'query_builder' => function(\Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository $er) {
                                       return $er->createQueryBuilder('i')
                                       ->orderBy('i.name', 'ASC');
                }
        ));
}
```

Comment: Don't know if it fits my needs? Actually that field must be editable and not a choice. I really need it to be a text. I need to: get the ID of the current user inside the buildform, use that ID to perform a query, get a text value, use that text value to prepopulate a text field.

Comment: Another solution probably would be to have access to the DB inside the user entity, so that i can implement the getLicense() method to perform the DB search and return the appropriate value. But again I don't know how to do it :/

Comment: Have you read the documentation on the entity field? I'd suggest also updating your original question to reflect your wishes.

Comment: Yes I've read the documentation and as far as I understand the Entity field is a choice field, which is not what I need.

Comment: You are correct..I think, if you want to mix the editing and saving of your Entities, you might be better of building a custom solution and skipping the Entity-based formbuilder altogether.

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep your User form and add the getting and saving of the seperate 'license' field through AJAX calls, skipping the main form logic.